# Prove that $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=A$

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles, radicals, area

In 50 AD, the Heron of Alexandria came up with the well-known formula, that, given the three side lengths of a triangle (or even two and an angle, thanks to trigonometry) you can get the area of said triangle by using this formula:

$$
\text{if } s=\frac{a+b+c}{2},\\
\text{then} A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$$

But the book it came with (mathematics 1001) did not give a mathematical proof to this. So I tried and failed to get a proof to this. This is how my train wreck went…

$$\begin{align}
\text{equation }&\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\\
\text{substitute }&\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{2}(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-a)(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-b)(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c)}\\
\text{eliminate fractions}&\sqrt{a+b+c(a+b+c-2a)(a+b+c-2b)(a+b+c-2c)}\\
\text{comb. Like terms }&\sqrt{a+b+c(b+c-a)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}\\
\text{associative property }&\sqrt{(a+(b+c)((b+c)-a))((a-(b+c))(a+(b-c)))}\\
\text{difference of 2 squares }&\sqrt{((b+c)^2-a^2)(a^2-b^2-c^2)}\\
\text{square of two numbers }& \sqrt{((b^2+bc+c^2)-a^2)(a^2-b^2-c^2)}\\
\text{polynomial multiplication}& \sqrt{2(a^2b^2-b^2c^2+a^2c^2)+a^2(b-c+a^2)-(b+c)(b^3+c^3)}\\
\end{align}$$
The issue is, I don't know how to get to $A$, the area. Does anyone know how to continue the proof train?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why sould $$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=0$$ it is a formula by Heron

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner whoops

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I am sorry but you should take care. It's not the first time that your remarks do not bring anything, even worse are not understandable : 1) Where is it mentionned that $A=0$ ? 2) the fact that it"s Heron's formula is mentionned in the first line of the text.

Comment: You can have a look at: [Proof of Heron's Formula for the area of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576831).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a triangle $ABC$.

$[ABC]=\frac{ab}{2}\sin C$

$=\frac{ab}{2}\sqrt{1-\cos^2 C}$

$=\frac{ab}{2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right)^2}$

$=\sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2}{4}\left[1-\frac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}{4a^2b^2}\right]}$

$=\sqrt{\frac{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}{16}}$

$=\sqrt{\frac{(2ab+a^2+b^2-c^2)(2ab-a^2-b^2+c^2)}{16}}$

$=\sqrt{\frac{((a+b)^2-c^2)(c^2-(a-b)^2)}{16}}$

$=\sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)}{16}}$

$=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$

Hence proved. Hope it helps

Comment: *sigh*... this is why I want to get a better grasp on trig and calculus by the end of 2018. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah learning calculus and high level trigonometry is very important in mathematics study. But I hardly can imagine anyone to master it within 4 days.

Comment: See the nice and original proof of Heron's formula in (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02816.pdf)

Comment: That proof too is good.

Comment: Wonderful.Heron would have liked your proof.

Comment: @manthanein you do realize it's still 2017, right??

Comment: I am really sorry. I misread it as "by the end of 2017". Sorry once again

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for the proof: [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

Comment: Fact: at least 25% of these math questions are answerable by looking at wikipedia. Notice, people!!!

Comment: @AlexanderDay yes it's meaningless write down here a proof that is given there!

Comment: Most of the rest were solved by Fermat, Bernoulli, Euler, or Ramanujan.