# heron's formula proof

Tags: proof-explanation, area

I have seen an interesting proof of Heron's formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1338282/672445). It is very simple, but I do not understand one point. The author demands, that the formula should contain factor $(a+b+c)$, because when we take $a=b=c=0$, the area of the triangle should be zero. And because of other reasons the formula should be like this:
$$S=k\cdot\sqrt{
(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)
}$$
where $k$ is a certain konstant. I understand, that this formula is homogeneous of degree 2, which it is supposed to be.

**But my question is** - why it could not be for example like this:
$$S=k\cdot
\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2+c^2}
\cdot
\sqrt{
(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)
}$$
because it's also homogeneous of degree 2 and colapses in case, when $a=b=c=0$?

Or is this not a proof, but just an analysis of the Heron's formula?

Comment: I think you are right. The factor $a^2+b^2+c^2$ (and many similar candidates) cannot be ruled out.

Comment: I believe that's not a rigorous proof, but an intuitive analysis... +1 anyway.

Comment: You're correct. Indeed, because the author has stated that, for instance, $a+b-c$ must be a factor, the requirement that $a=b=c=0$ must yield a zero area has already been covered. For all we know, the missing factor could be *any* (homogeneous) combination of $a$, $b$, $c$ with the proper degree.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to explain it. Let $s$ denote the triangle's semiperimeter. The $a+b-c$ factor is $2s-2c$, but let's talk about $s-c$ instead because we have a proportionality constant anyway. Now, [for a cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula) we get an area of $\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}$ (with $s:=(a+b+c+d)/2$ for sides $a,\,b,\,c,\,d$), of which Heron's formula is the $d=0$ special case obtained by sliding one vertex onto another. So instead of trying to motivate Heron, let's try to motivate Brahmagupta's formula. The linked "proof" has a geometry justification for $s-c$; all the other factors come the same way. What's more, at that point the square-rooted product already has the units of area, so we need no more factors with units of length.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from the book Trigonometry - I.M. Gelfand

"It must be linear in a, b, c and it must be symmetric in these three variables. This means that the factor must be of the form k(a+b+c), for some constant k."