# A New Algebraic Proof of Heron's Formula?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification

I noticed that many proofs for Herons formula use the properties of angles, which is why I wanted to show a proof that doesn't involve any,  and seems to be simpler than the usual methods that are applied.

A triangle with side lengths $a, b, c,$ where $c$ is the greatest side length and an altitude($h$) that intercepts $c$ such that $c$ is the  sum of two side lengths ,
$c = m + n$, using Pythagorean theorem and the area formula of a triangle,  we can prove Herons formula.

First we find $a$ and $b$ in terms of $m$ and $n$ using Pythagorean theorem:

$a^2 - m^2 = h^2$

$b^2 - n^2 = h^2$

$a^2 - m^2 = b^2 - n^2$

$a^2 - b^2 = m^2 - n^2$

Then using $c = m + n$, eliminate $m$:

$a^2 - b^2 = (c-n)^2 - n^2$

$a^2 - b^2 = c^2 - 2cn$

$n = \frac{1}{2c}(c^2 + b^2 - a^2)$

We can Eliminate $n$ from $b^2 - n^2 = h^2$ to find $h$:

$h = \sqrt{b^2 - (\frac{1}{2c}(c^2 + b^2 - a^2))^2}$

Plugging this into the area formula ($A = \frac{1}{2}ch$) gives:

$A = \frac{1}{2}c\sqrt{ b^2 - (\frac{1}{2c}(c^2 + b^2 - a^2))^2} $

$A = \frac{1}{2}c\sqrt{ \frac{1}{4c^2}(2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2-a^4-b^4+2b^2c^2-c^4)} $

$A = \sqrt{\frac{1}{16}(c^2 - (a - b)^2)(( a + b)^2 - c^2)} $

$A = \sqrt{\frac{1}{16}(a + b - c)( a + b + c)( b + c - a)(a + c - b)} $

$A = \sqrt{s(s - a)(s- b)(s- c)}$

Q.E.D.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should mention that $s = (a + b + c)/2$. There is nothing wrong with this proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of Heron's Formula for the area of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576831/proof-of-herons-formula-for-the-area-of-a-triangle)

Comment: Nice proof, but you should check the case when $c = m - n$  to complete it, I think. It's just a formality of course.

Comment: @Light Yagami I am wondering why this proof has been closed, I have checked the other question but I do note see the similarity between the proofs in the comments, could you please explain?

Comment: @SpoonedBread: Your proof, while not new, is (mostly) fine. As @ Timur notes, you need to consider the possibility of $c=m-n$ (or $c=n-m$). One way to do that is declare $c$ the longest side, which eliminates those possibilities (why?); alternatively, write $c=|m\pm n|$. Also, you can proceed without favoring $m$ over $n$ by using a more symmetric argument: $$c^2=|m\pm n|^2\quad\to\quad c^2=m^2+n^2\pm2mn\quad\to\quad (c^2-m^2-n^2)^2=4m^2n^2$$ Then substitute $m^2=a^2-h^2$ and $n^2=b^2-h^2$, expand, cancel, isolate $4c^2h^2$ (aka, $16A^2$), factor the rest, and finally obtain the result.

Comment: @SpoonedBread I think the implicit suggestion is that you post your proof as an answer at the linked question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I was hoping to bring more attention to it which is why I did not originally post it as a solution for the question, as it was asked along time ago, but I have done it now.